# Windows 10 BSOD (0x00000050)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

So I was watching a video on Youtube and while I was watching that video I came across the blue screen of death which said the following:

Stop code: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
What failed: nvlddmkm.sys

After getting the blue screen, I checked the event viewer and got a 0x00000050 code. I haven't added or removed any hardware recently, I have windows 10 automatically updating my drivers

I have only gotten this blue screen once and it happened before I started asking my question, I should also mention that I was watching a twitch stream as well before the BSOD was triggered, which leads me into my questions that I have:

1. Could this be a faulty hardware issue or does it have to be a driver that was automatically updated by windows that caused the crash? Under the device manager I do have the automatically update drivers ticked, so I am wondering whether or not if it is that. Like I said earlier, I haven't made any hardware/software changes to my computer recently and I have the automatically update drivers option ticked.
2. Do Nvidia drivers crash all the time and then fix themselves after the BSOD and has anyone ran into an issue similar to mine even though the option for automatically updating drivers is checked?
3. Could it be the anti virus that I'm using which is built into windows and is called Windows Defender, and could it be the update that caused the BSOD?
4. Should I worry about this error/stop code and treat it as something that has generated a fatal error only if it has happened once, when I don't know whether or not it will happen again?

I did install a game onto my computer yesterday which is called Apex Legends, and I'm not sure if that's what triggered it today, I haven't had the chance to play it at all since all I was doing was just watching videos on youtube and a live stream on twitch. if you guys have any information you can provide me with, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which browser were you using to watch YouTube?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox, I forgot to mention I also had discord running in the background as well, not sure if that has to do with anything related to the crash.

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Options -> General -> Performance, do you have "Use recommended performance settings" checked?  It may be that you need to uncheck that and turn off hardware acceleration.  Strange that this would only start happening now after you installed that game.

Comment: Yes I do have that checked, I just unchecked it just now. When you say hardware acceleration, are you talking about discord? I did uncheck hardware acceleration on discord but when I opened it, it was very laggy. Other than that i have unchecked both "Use recommended performance settings" and the "Use hardware acceleration when available" unchecked like you said earlier.

Comment: Hardware acceleration allows Firefox to use your GPU for rendering and such.  It's possible that FF and Discord were trying to access the same address on the GPU (not an expert in this area), but your BSOD definitely came from your NVIDIA driver, so it's possible.

Comment: I have hardware acceleration turned on in Discord but I turned it off on firefox as well as the recomended performance settings like you said earlier. Let's see if that will make any difference, hopefully no BSOD's. I'll let you know if I do get one. I appreciate your help, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  Report back if it doesn't do it and I'll add that as an answer.  I suspect there may be more to it, but if that works for you, great!

Comment: Find the recommended driver version at Nvidia, download and install it. With proper drivers installed and kept up-to-date - the Nvidia tool is fine for that - the Windows Update won't touch those drivers.

Comment: I would do that Gabriela but even if i update the driver for it, I'm afraid another problem may arise from it. Like I said earlier, this has only appeared once. So I'm waiting as to whether or not the first solution will work and I'll give it at least a day or two to see if that resolves the problem. If not, then I may take the Nvidia driver update into consideration. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Jonsca i have a quick question, so my content process limit on Firefox was set to 8, however I was told that the default was 4, should I check "Use hardware acceleration when available" except set the content process limit to 4 and leave the "Use recommended performance settings" unchecked? Again, i appreciate your help thank you so much!